# Notice: Trying to get property 'work_email' of non-object in Project_New_FR\forms-give.php on line 13

Tags: php, json

> Notice: Trying to get property 'work_email' of non-object in
> Project_New_FR\forms-give.php on line 13
>
> etc. etc.
>
> Notice: Trying to get property '<property>' of non-object in
> Project_New_FR\forms-give.php on line 27

I wrote code:

```
<?php
 ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

 require 'database.php';
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
     copy($_FILES['jsonFile']['tmp_name'] , 'jsonFiles/'.$_FILES['jsonFile']['name']);
     $data = file_get_contents('jsonFiles/'.$_FILES['jsonFile']['name']);
     $d=json_decode($data);
     print_r($d);
     foreach($d as $ds){
         $stmt = $conn->prepare('insert into details(id,full_name,work_email,mobile_phone,job_company_name,job_company_location_locality,job_company_location_region,job_company_location_street_address,job_company_location_postal_code,location_locality,location_region,location_country,location_continent,location_street_address,location_postal_code,phone_numbers,emails) values("",:full_name,:work_email,:mobile_phone,:job_company_name,:job_company_location_locality,:job_company_location_region,:job_company_location_street_address,:job_company_location_postal_code,:location_locality,:location_region,:location_country,:location_continent,:location_street_address,:location_postal_code,:phone_numbers,:emails) ');
         $stmt->bindValue('full_name', $ds->full_name);
         $stmt->bindValue('work_email', $ds->work_email);
         $stmt->bindValue('mobile_phone', $ds->mobile_phone);
         $stmt->bindValue('job_company_name', $ds->job_company_name);
         $stmt->bindValue('job_company_location_locality', $ds->job_company_location_locality);
         $stmt->bindValue('job_company_location_region', $ds->job_company_location_region);
         $stmt->bindValue('job_company_location_street_address', $ds->job_company_location_street_address);
         $stmt->bindValue('job_company_location_postal_code', $ds->job_company_location_postal_code);
         $stmt->bindValue('location_locality', $ds->location_locality);
         $stmt->bindValue('location_region', $ds->location_region);
         $stmt->bindValue('location_country', $ds->location_country);
         $stmt->bindValue('location_continent', $ds->location_continent);
         $stmt->bindValue('location_street_address', $ds->location_street_address);
         $stmt->bindValue('location_postal_code', $ds->location_postal_code);
         $stmt->bindValue('phone_numbers', $ds->phone_numbers);
         $stmt->bindValue('emails', $ds->emails);
      
         $stmt->execute();

        }
    }
?>
```

## Print_r `$d` Output:

> ```
> stdClass Object (
>     [id] => oUtNZ6WK47citf2SLvtvrg_0000 
>     [full_name] => phary yoeun 
>     [first_name] => phary
>     [middle_initial] => 
>     [middle_name] =>
>     [last_name] => yoeun
>     [gender] =>
>     [birth_year] =>
>     [birth_date] =>
>     [linkedin_url] => linkedin.com/in/phary- 
>  ....
> )
> ```

Comment: [reading the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will help you.

Comment: ok, Thank you help me

Comment: @Martin `json_decode()` is supposed to create objects, not associative arrays, unless you use the second argument `true`.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to prepare and bind the statement every time through the loop. You do that once, and call `execute()` in the loop.

Comment: It sounds like the array contains a mix of data types. What does the `print_r()` show right before the error happens?

Comment: @Barmar yes sorry, that's my bad phrasing on that comment. The object returned by `JOSN_decode` from the comment by OP looks like it only contains one set of elements whereas the foreach is looking for multiple sets. I know I've phrased that pooorly but I hope you get what I mean `:-)`

Comment: Judging from the comment by OP with the output of their `print_r($d);`, the `$ds` in the foreach loop appears to be an object attribute, not an object in its own right.

Comment: You're right. I thought it was `print_r($ds)`. The similar names are very confusing.

Comment: So the issue is that the file doesn't contain an array of objects, it just has one object. You shouldn't have a loop.

Comment: If the file is supposed to contain multiple objects, you need to fix the application that creates it.

Comment: no , i want to import large json data set

Comment: @HeartKurunegala currently `$d` is an object full of property's; it is not an object full of other objects which you code expects. As stated by Barmar you therefore need to fix the source JSON data. `:-)`

Comment: You can better see the issue you are facing by doing: `print_r(gettype($ds));` *inside* your foreach loop. You are expecting *Object* but what you get will be *string*

Comment: `foreach($d as $ds){     print_r(gettype($ds)); `

Comment: Thank you bother , you lot of help me.......